# reading json [object object] result from ajax odata call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf, odata

I am making a call to my oData WCF service hosted on my local PC and the result I get when I pass result to alert box is [object object].
The console.log(data) is showing structure as follows

```
[object Object]
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: {
         [functions]: ,
         __proto__: null
      },
      odata.metadata: "http://localhost:65401/sdrservice.svc/$metadata#usermasters",
      value: [
         0: {
            [functions]: ,
            __proto__: {
               [functions]: ,
               __proto__: null
            },
            company: "CBI",
            Id: 129576,
            lockcode: "azxh",
            name: "Azhar Husain"
         },
         length: 1
      ]
   }
```

I want to read the value of company and name from the object of the user in jquery. Please guide me how to access those fields with the exact syntax. I have already tried using **data.d** or **data[0].company** nothing works for me.

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` for printing your object instead.

Comment: i already utilized and found that it changes it to a string which can be used to display in alert box. But my concern is with how can i reach to **company & name** field of the object as I need to fetch company and name of user for display purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON structure has a property called value, which is an array. To access the company and name of the first element in this property:

```
var company = data.value[0].company;
var name = data.value[0].name;
```

Comment: Thanks for your upfront reply i really appreciate the stack overflow and its users for such a quick mechanism. I will marked the answer as accepted once it reaches the minimum time limit.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, data.value[0].company ..

Comment: Thanks for your reply it worked. Your single line reply also helped me in understanding reading json object array concept.